# Algorithm Recursive Method

Tags: algorithm

I am required to write a recursive class method `sumNum` according to the description below. And I'm not allowed to use any loop in my method but may use % (modulus) operator.

Still new to this module, therefore I needed to know how to write this method out.

A function `sumNum (int n)` takes as parameter a positive integer. The function will return the sum of digits of the parameter that are less than 5.

(E.g. `sumDigit(84293841)` returns 14, which is the sum of digits 4, 2, 3, 4 and 1). Other digits that are greater or equal to 5 are excluded in the summation.

(E.g. `sumDigit(64890272)` returns 8, which is the sum of digits 4, 0, 2 and 2).

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Its okay! I managed to solved it alr! At first, I was stucked with how to sum up the digits that is less than 5. Thankyou!

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to achieve this in C++:

```
unsigned int sumLessThan5Digits(unsigned int n) {
    return n == 0 ? 0 : 
        (sumLessThan5Digits(n/10) + ((n % 10) < 5 ? (n % 10) : 0));
}

int main() {
    std::cout << sumLessThan5Digits(84293841) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sumLessThan5Digits(64890272) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy!

Comment: If you think this answer is correct, please accept.

Comment: @BloodStark please accept the question, so that others may benefit from it.

Comment: I see, here is how to do it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work